# Where does "simia" come from?

Tags: etymology, animals

The [L&S entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=simia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) for *simia* ("ape") says that the etymology is dubious, and it is perhaps akin to *similis*.
What do other sources have to say on the etymology?
Are there popular theories or is it perhaps still unclear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Walde, following Kretschmer, thinks it is from σῑμός “snub-nosed”.

Comment: *OLD* agrees, saying that it's 'prob[ably]' from the Latin adjective *simus* (Greek σιμός), 'having a flattened nose.'

Comment: Tacet *De Vaan.*

Comment: . ...implying that he accepts that it is a loan word.